# Replacing Java Objects at runtime

Tags: java, object, garbage-collection

The below class is initialised on the `init()` method of a servlet. 
`objA` is only used for reading, the `refreshA`-method needs to be called periodically to replace it with a new instance of `A`.

The problem :
    After periodical updates, a memory leak appears. (I am guessing there are <strike>some dangling references</strike> multiple copies of the `A` existing)

```
public Class A {

private static volatile A objA;

public static A getA(){

    if(objA == null){

        synchronized (A.class){

            if(objA == null){
                objA = new A(); //takes a long time to initialise and memory heavy
                return objA;
            }

        }
    }
    return objA;
}

    public static void refreshA (A newObjA){
       // best way to do this ?
       /*
        objA = newObjA; 
       */
    }
}
```

Kind of hacky :

I could use 
`ConcurrentHashMap<String,A> -> get("OBJ-A"), replace("OBJ-A", newObjA)`

this would use the **ReentrantReadWriteLock** but I havent tried it yet.

So what would be the best way to implement `refreshA()`? Keeping in mind that the GC should remove the old reference.

Comment: If the old object is not being collected it's because it's linked from somewhere else.  (But of course, many suspected "memory leaks" are due merely to the nature of how GC works -- heap grows until the limit is reached, then is collected.)

Comment: Just synchronizing on A.class and setting the reference is enough here. @HotLicks is right, your problem isn't in this class.

Comment: No leak found here. Think of the bigger picture. How other classes use the result of getA()? Besides, if A is a heavy object to create, why not refresh it by replacing it and not by copying states from other objects/sources into objA?

Comment: (Do keep in mind that if you replace the object, someone may still be holding a reference to the old one, and may use values from that old one.)

Comment: @alfredx and @ HotLicks suppose multiple requests are using the old reference and only reading from it and concurrently the object in class A is replaced with a new instance. these requests when done will have no reference to the old instance and hence should be derefernced and subsequent requests should be using only the new instance.Hope tht was not confusing :P 
Well this object cannot be updated in parts and swapping it with a new instance after the pre processing is the only option.
Also made sure that the requests are not passing the reference to the same object anywhere or storing it.

Comment: If the old object isn't being collected it's because there's still a reference to it somewhere.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the requirement behind the scene. Anyway, if leakage is suspected, I personally would use tools to anlayze/diagnose the JVM/heap to find out more. [See my other comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676394/gcviewer-pattern-analysis/19677237#19677237)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, double-checked locking is not recommended
, see en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking.

As for the replacable field, you can use an AtomicReference.

And regarding the memory leak, consider giving out a proxy to the actual object. This way you can swap out the backing instance and be sure that noone keeps a reference to the old backing object.

Comment: will end up using a enum singleton :)
AtomicReference sounds good ... damn java is fraking huge !!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have figured out how to (re-)implement the singleton and the refresh operation.

I want to focus on some of the other things in your Question.

1. (Pure) Java cannot have dangling references.  The values in any reference in any live object in Java will either be `null` or valid reference to an existing object.  This even applies to unreachable objects.
2. Dangle references (i.e. pointers that no longer point to a valid object) don't cause storage leaks.  Rather they are a sign of heap corruption.  In Java, if the JVM (including the GC) attempted to use a dangling reference, the result would most likely be a hard crash.
3. If is not entirely clear what you think the connection between the memory leak and your periodic update is.  However:

   - The periodic update is almost certainly not the *cause* of this memory leak.  Certainly it is not, on the evidence of the code you have shown us.
   - A periodic update is not guaranteed to cure a memory leak, unless the `A` static holds the one and only long-term reference to the `A` instance that is leaking.  Indeed, if you "refresh" the `A` singleton in this way, there is a distinct possibility that you will *cause* a leak.  For example, if some other code calls the `getA()` method and caches the result somewhere, when `A.refreshA()` is called you will end up with TWO `A` instances in existence, and the first one has effectively leaked.

Finally your refresh operation is breaking the implicit singleton semantics of `A`.  That could cause all sorts of *other* problems, including threading issues.

---

If you suspect that your `A` class is the *cause* of a memory leak, then a better approach to fixing the problem is to:

- figure out what part of `A`'s state is the dangerous part of the leak, and
- add a synchronized `instance` method to `A` to *clear* that state.

Note that not all leaks are harmful.  An object that exists for the lifetime of the application (e.g. a `static`) could appear to be a leak (to a leak detector) but is not going to cause any problems.

Comment: poor choice of words regarding dangling references what I meant was the 2nd bullet on the third point, two or more instances of `A` existing. But I've made sure such a caching step does not occur anywhere. So there exists one method that does `getA()` and creates a local object of `A` from which data is read, response is spit out and returns void. In this process if the switching takes place what happens to the old reference will it be up for GC ?